# How can i log this exception?

Tags: android, exception, android-logcat

I want to log this exception but i don't know how to do it:

```
catch (ParseException pe) {
updateStatus("Connection Error.");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the android.util.Log class:

```
Log.e("App-or-Class-identifier-for-filtering", "error message", pe);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i made Log.e("tag", pe) and it doesn't worked ! now it works. THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

If by *log this exception* you mean write a line to LogCat, just use the [**`Log`** class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) :

```
Log.e("tag", "Some error message you want to log");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pe.printStackTrace() also.